# C++/Cli literal Array Initialization

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to create a constant array in managed c++ and am getting stuck.  I've searched around but haven't come across any good examples of how to do this.

What I'd like is the equivalent of:

```
const unsigned char myConstArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Right now I'm staring at this:

```
literal array<Byte>^ myConstArray = gcnew array<Byte> { 1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Which I gather is not right, since Visual Studio complains that I cannot use gcnew in a constant expression.  Not sure where to go here, any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not work with the `literal` like that because:

> A data member marked as `literal` must be initialized when declared and **the value must be a constant integral, enum, or string type**. Conversion from the type of the initialization expression to the type of the static const data-member must not require a user-defined conversion.

[literal (C++ Component Extensions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yzft952.aspx)

...however it is quite strange that `literal` is an an equivalent of `static const` but by using `static const` it compiles without errors.

Creating a read-only property is another way you could return the array:

```
ref class Test1 {
public:
    Test1() {
        myArray = gcnew cli::array<Byte> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    }

    property cli::array<Byte>^ MyArray {
        cli::array<Byte>^ get() {
            return myArray;
        };  
    }

private:

    cli::array<Byte>^ myArray;

};
```

Comment: Hmm.. If I change it to static const I instead get warnings of "const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported".  It does get past this point in compilation now.  I suppose I can just make a regular array, make it private, and hope it doesn't get overwritten if there's no other way of doing this.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that!  Thanks!

Comment: Worked great, and it actually simplified things a fair bit.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
std::initializer_list<unsigned char>>({1, 2, 3,4,5,6};
```

I'm not sure if this applies to managed C++ but initializer lists are a C++11 construct that is inherently const and allows begin and end semantics to be applied but not array indexing. so as long as a ranged based for will work you can use this array.

Comment: Please explain what this block of code is.  Right now, it's not very useful as an answer and in danger of deletion.